# Clique Theorem from Graph Theory

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am trying to determine an interesting problem here. I want to determine if I have a graph of N vertices, for different subgraphs of k vertices (where k <= N), how many edges can I add before the graph must contain at least one k-clique?

(A clique is defined as: A subset of an undirected graph in which every two vertices are connected by an edge.)

I was told this was called the "Clique Theorem"; however, upon entering this into Google, it does not seem to exist under this term.

I tried to look at this for different values of N and k. I don't know how accurate they are, but for instance:

```
 N = 4: (k=2-->1, k=3-->5, k=4-->6)
 N = 5: (k=2-->1, k=3-->6, k=4-->8, k=5-->10)
 N = 6: (k=2-->1, k=3-->10, k=4-->12, k=5-->15, k=6-->15)
 ...
 N = 8: (k=2-->1, k=3-->16, k=4-->18,...)
```

I am not even confident what I have concluded above is correct, but as I try to solve larger N values, my drawings become too messy. Hence, I stopped at N=8/k=4, because I have 18 edges and cannot scan every combination of four nodes within.

If you have any ideas for these questions, could you kindly respond?: Is there an easier/more intelligent way to go about this? Does such a formula exist for this problem? Is there another term for this problem other than "Clique Theorem"?

Thank you.

Comment: I have never heard of a "Clique theorem" but this seems to be referring to [Turán's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your Q isTuran's graph & number.

Partition the vertex set into k-1 (nearly-)even sets. put an edge in between 
every pair of vertices (u,v) whenever u and v aren't both in one of these partitions. 
It is Turan's proof that this graph is a full (k-1)-partite graph-- has the *maximum 
possible edge-count* while it contains no k-cliques. 
The addition of **any** new edge forms a k-clique.

The edge-count on this graph is [Turan's number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TuransTheorem.html) for T(n=|V|, k-1)-- max. possible #edges on a graph of n vertices without ending up with a k-clique. 
By the same token, 1+T(n=|V|, k-1) tells the 
the minimum number of edges on an n-vertex graph that guarantees a k-clique.

Eg.: For n=8, k=4, the maximum number of edges you can have without having a 4-clique is 24.